# Mann-Kendall trend test

Tags: references, hypothesis-testing, trend

I'm trying to find some information about the Mann-Kendall trend test. I've tried to make some research on google but the main reference that I find is the 1976 book "Rank correlation methods" by Kendall. Obviously this book isn't easy to find so I hope that you could give some links to find some practical information about it

Answer (score 1):

It's also known just as the Mann test.  I find it in Nonparametric Statistical Methods, Hollander and Wolfe, and a discussion of its power in  
[The Power of Statistical Tests for Trend Detection](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mann%20trend%20test&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEUQFjAE&url=http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/engineering/issues/muh-03-27-4/muh-27-4-5-0206-6.pdf&ei=igvcTpirGoeviQK7hPHZCQ&usg=AFQjCNEM8p8ysa2IqyfKGichondrz890qA&cad=rja).  It's in the R package Kendall.

Hopefully, this will be enough to get you going.